# How to do Run Cron Automatically When Re-Index And Refresh Cache Required

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, reindex

Ask continuously re-index and refresh cache, how can i set Re-Index and Refresh cache done by own when it's required. Is it possible ??

Answer (score 1):

There's a few modules that will run off the cron and reindex and re-refresh the caches when it's required.

- For re-inedexing I'd recommend Mirasvit's Fast Asynchronous
  Re-indexing module -
  https://mirasvit.com/magento-extensions/magento-asynchronous-reindex.html
  (There is a price tag attached to this though)
- For re-freshing the cache once invalidated -
  https://github.com/MichaelThessel/magento-cache-refresh
- You can also checkout - https://github.com/magento-hackathon/AsyncIndex (For a free alternative for the Mirasvit's module.